# How to write multiple unittests in dart in multiple files?

Tags: dart

I am writing some Dart library and want to have it unittested. I created directory `test` and want to put my tests in here. Because I am going to have a lot of tests, I want to have them separated to multiple files. My questions is, what is the Dart convention, how to do that. I want to have my tests easily run all, however, I also want to be able to run just one file of tests.

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is common to separate tests into multiple files. I am including an example of how you can do that.

Imagine that you have 2 files with tests, foo_test.dart, bar_test.dart that contain tests for your program.  foo_test.dart could look something like this:

```dart
library foo_test;

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main() {
  test('foo test', () {
    expect("foo".length, equals(3));
  });
}
```

And bar_test.dart could look something like this:

```dart
library bar_test;

import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

void main() {
  test('bar test', () {
    expect("bar".length, equals(3));
  });
}
```

You could run either file, and the test contained in that file would execute.

The, I would create something like an all_tests.dart file that would import the tests from foo_test.dart and bar_test.dart. Here is what all_tests.dart could look like:

```dart
import 'foo_test.dart' as foo_test;
import 'bar_test.dart' as bar_test;

void main() {
  foo_test.main();
  bar_test.main();
}
```

If you executed all_tests.dart, both the tests from foo_test.dart and bar_test.dart would execute.

One thing to note: for all this to work, you need to declare foo_test.dart and bar_test.dart as libraries (see the first line of each file). Then, in all_tests.dart, you can use import syntax to fetch the contents of the declared libraries.

This is how I organize most of my tests.

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool that does exactly that, [Dart Test Runner](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test_runner). An excerpt from that page:

> Dart Test Runner will automatically detect and run all the tests in your Dart project in the correct environment (VM or Browser).

It detects any test writen in a file suffixed with `_test.dart` where your test code is inside a `main()` function. It doesn't have any problem detecting and running [unittest](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests) tests.

It's pretty easy to install it and run it. Just two commands:

```
$ pub global activate test_runner
$ pub global run test_runner
```

For more options, please check [Dart Test Runner](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test_runner) page.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to have multiple files to isolate a test - see [Running only a single test](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/cookbook/#running-only-a-single-test) and [Running a limited set of tests](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#running-a-limited-set-of-tests).

> To isolate a test, change `test()` to `solo_test()`.

So you can put all your tests in the same file (or into several parts).

Answer (score 2):

In case it can be helpful for anybody while running a bunch of tests at once,

I was writing tests but my **test file** names **did not end with   `*_test.dart`**
So I was not able to run all tests at once.

If you want to run all tests at once, **it's mandatory to end your dart file with _test.dart.**